# Permitir o uso do capslock em uma função RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou utilizando uma função com expressão regular para validar um `input`, permitindo digitar somente letras, e números. No entanto, quando uso as teclas capslock ou shift para letras maiúsculas ele está bloqueando e emitindo o `alert`.

Como eu posso permitir o uso do caps lock e shift apenas, nessa função?

```
function letrasNumeros(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\b]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    var whichCode = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    alert("Não é permitido utlizar caracteres especiais ou espaços no nome de usuário, é permitido somente letras e números.");
    document.getElementById('apelidoCliente').value = '';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Você está usando uma propriedade obsoleta que não deve ser mais utilizada, veja https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which  . Provavelmente está recebendo essa propriedade obsoleta através de um evento [`keypress` que também é obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event), considere reescrever o seu código para fazer uso dos eventos [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) ou [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

Comment: Outra forma de fazer é usar o evento `input`, que detecta qualquer alteração no campo (não só digitação, mas também control-V, por exemplo). Aí vc verifica se todo o valor corresponde à regex, algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/noLydq63/1/

Comment: @hkotsubo Excelente!! Consegui resolver o problema, inclusive atualizei outras funções aqui, muito obrigado.